# Google Drive SDK - JavaScript : How to list SHARED FILES (not shared with me)

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm looking for a way of finding a list of a user's **shared files** on google drive sdk using JavaScript.

Important: I am not looking for a list of files that are 'shared with me'.

What I have at the moment lists the files 'shared with me' and I'm wonder if there is a way of changing the 'sharedWithMe' query string parameter, to list the files that I have shared??

```
// Load the API and make an API call.  Display the results on the screen.
function makeApiCall() {
    // Load drive
    gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {
        // Request files (q is query string, to filter files)
        var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list ( {'maxResults': 200,'q':"trashed=false and sharedWithMe"} );
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Dave

Comment: I found the answer myself:

List the email address of the user you have shared files with in the 'readers' parameter in the q query string. (Note: 'readers' is a collection of users who have permission to view the file)e.g.:  
  
    // Request files (q is query string, to filter files)
    var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list ( {'recipientUser@gmail.com' in readers"} );
Thanks anyway!  
  
Dave

Comment: You can answer your own question by providing an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:

List the email address of the user you have shared files with in the 'readers' parameter in the q query string. (Note: 'readers' is a collection of users who have permission to view the file)e.g.:

```
// Check if recipient is in list of readers
var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list ( {'recipientUser@gmail.com' in readers"} );
```

Thanks!

Dave

Comment: this solution does not take into account files shared by someone else and you also. To keep those out of the results, you should use {"'recipientUser@gmail.com' in readers and 'me' in owners"}

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for all owned, shared files without knowing who they are shared with, you'd need to use a search query of `'me' in owners` and then further filter down the list based on which returned files have `shared: true` set.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect when you don't know who the files are shared with. My answer (below) is for when you are looking for files shared with one particular user.